# How can I replace the price_id of stripe to my already existed price_id stored in my database

Tags: php, stripe-payments

The goal im trying to achieve is to replace the price_id to make the stripe session with my stored price_id in my database :

```
$session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
    'success_url' => 'https://example.com/success',
  'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/cancel',
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'line_items' => [
    [
      'price' => 'price_1JX1Yxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',// I want to change price_1JX... with the one I have stored on my DB //
      'quantity' => 1,
    ],
  ],
  'mode' => 'payment',
```

in my controller:

```
$price_id = DB::table('products')->where('slug', $this->slug)->value('price_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it like this

```
$session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
    'success_url' => 'https://example.com/success',
  'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/cancel',
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'line_items' => [
    [
      'price' => $price_id,
      'quantity' => 1,
    ],
  ],
  'mode' => 'payment',
```